# Is there a way to make a network graph in plotly with curved edges?

Tags: python, plotly, networkx

I'm trying to make an interactive graph on plotly, where I first create the network graph using networkx, and then graph it with plotly so that it can be hosted and be interative and shared, very similar to what's described here: https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/

I would like to make the edges curved -- in networkx I can do this with `connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.3"`. How do I do this in Plotly?